# "truffle migrate" running all migrations everytime

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, ganache

I have a very weird behavior happening whenever I run "truffle migrate". Ideally, as per the documentation, it states:

> This will run all migrations located within your project's migrations directory. At their simplest, migrations are simply a set of managed deployment scripts. If your migrations were previously run successfully, truffle migrate will start execution from the last migration that ran, running only newly created migrations. If no new migrations exist, truffle migrate won't perform any action at all

But for me, on the contrary, it's running all migration every time i.e. starting from 1_initial_migration till the last migration file I have. I am using Ganache for local testing. Is it something related to the code setup or am I missing anything important that needs to be done for migration.

Output of running truffle migrate:

```
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js   Replacing Migrations...   
...0xf698fa2021847daaef0cedfc008976fbcc499eafc6f9c1eac6cc011faca77593 
Migrations: 0xecfcab0a285d3380e488a39b4bb21e777f8a4eac Saving 
successful migration to network...   ... 
0x64df98e7d3f1cf5dc7eaa5264011714bf49802d9fda56003e202434903c2581b 
Saving artifacts... Running migration: 
2_factory_name_registry_migration.js   
Didn't deploy FactoryNameRegistry; using 
0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10  
...0x0f90f0c9086735cd74a83b30f597fa5363764eb8920d5ae0b47cb6b3267be627 
Saving successful migration to network...   ... 
0xf048fc893066a845ec584920ab57630b213db48a619e85fc12f8d3e966fb3525   
...0x81a7a0b188eadb39e207bd22fb3598830d166beb6b3f3bc7852f73dd303af6ef 
Saving artifacts...
```

Edit: this is happening without restarting Ganache, as I do understand restarting the server will cause this behaviour to happen naturally

Comment: the documentation says it will run all migrations from your migration folder. that is exactly what the `truffle migrate` command is doing. there is not problem here.

Comment: you are skipping later part of the statment that says: If your migrations were previously run successfully, truffle migrate will start execution from the last migration that was ran, running only newly created migrations. If no new migrations exists, truffle migrate won't perform any action at all

Comment: when migrating, truffle reads a network version from its deployed migration contract, if version has not changed truffle will not save the contracts to the network ( send transaction ). in your case it is saving its migration contract and the contract you have just changed. as you can see one of your contracts was not deployed to the network since you didn't change anything in it.

Comment: yes, I am aware of it, and that's the thing I am not changing anything on any contract. I am just running truffle migrate successively and it runs all migration file. The reason it's not running the one you are referring to is that with that particular Contract I am using {overwrite: false} in 2_factory_name_registry_migration.js

Comment: That is unexpected, cna you check if the build folder is present and is modified during the migration ?

Comment: yes I checked that, I mean to be 100% sure I am deleting the build folder. Then I run "truffle migrate" which obviously first compiles and then runs all the migration, which is working just fine. After this if I run truffle migrate again instantly it doesn't do any compilation but it still runs all the migrations again, which is the anomaly here

Comment: It is probably a problem with the migration contract, maybe you edited it or something.

Comment: you were actually right, I just discovered my webstorm IDE removed the following after upgrading to solidity 0.4.23: function Migrations() public {
  owner = msg.sender;
 }  because of which the address or reference was not being stored and thus migrations were running everytime.

Comment: Wow, Why would webstorm do that ? i run webstorm it never happened

Comment: I had a plugin installed for solidity lint and in the new 0.4.23 they have deprecated the old way of declaring the constructor so my plugin actually auto-fix any upgrade errors. so its the plugin not the webstorm to be blamed technically

Comment: ah i didn't have those upgrades,yet.

Comment: yes I am returning to 0.4.17 as well